# Laravel find() ignores duplicate id in controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a variable in my controller $course_id that is an array:

```
array:3 [▼
0 => 2
1 => 0
2 => 2
]
```

When I try and use it as part of my find statement any duplicate values get ignored so

```
$courses = Course::with(['orders'])->orderBy('id', 'asc')->find($course_id);
```

with the following in my view

```
<?php foreach($courses as $course){
echo $course->id;};
?>
```

Output is '02'
I need '202' 
Any idea how I can stop the duplicate from being overwritten?

There is a lot going on to get to this stage due to pivot tables etc however this is all found in my customer controller where I need to show their order and course details etc

```
 public function show($id)
{
    $customer = Customer::with(['orders'])->findOrFail($id);
    foreach($customer->orders as $order){
        $order_id[] = $order->id;
        $course_id[] = $order->course_id; 
        $delivery_mode_id[] = $order->delivery_mode;
        $campus_id[] = $order->location;

    };

    $orders = Order::with(['courses'])->orderBy('id', 'asc')->find($order_id);
    $courses = Course::with(['orders'])->orderBy('id', 'asc')->where($course_id);
    $delivery_modes = DeliveryMode::with('orders')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->find($delivery_mode_id);
    $campuses = Campus::with('orders')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->find($campus_id);

    return view('customers.show', compact('customer', 'courses', 'orders', 'delivery_modes', 'campuses', 'order'));

}
```

The following is how I need it to output, it works fine when the ID's are unique however when I order 2 of the same course, location, or delivery method the duplicates don't appear.

```
 <tbody>
        <tr>
        @foreach($courses as $course)
        <td style="border-bottom:0; border-right:1px solid #dbdbdb;">{{$course->name}}</td>
        @endforeach 
        </tr>

        <tr>
        @foreach($campuses as $campus)
        <td style="border-bottom:0; border-right:1px solid #dbdbdb;">{{$campus->name}}</td>
        @endforeach
        </tr>
        <tr>
        @foreach($delivery_modes as $delivery_mode)
        <td style="border-bottom:0; border-right:1px solid #dbdbdb;">{{$delivery_mode->name}}</td>
        @endforeach

        </tr>
        <tr>
        @foreach($orders as $order)
        <td style="border-bottom:0; border-right:1px solid #dbdbdb;"><?php $displaycomdate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($order->start_date)); echo $displaycomdate ?></td>
        @endforeach
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: your question is a little confusing here, find() method is used to query by primary key which has no duplicates, so it'll only returns results based on the primary key specified, perhaps it might be more helpful if you share what your Course table looks like

Comment: If you have the query `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id=1 OR id=1` how many results would you expect from that statement? Of course, it will only return one result, not two. This is essentially what you're doing. Instead of looping over the results, loop over the `$course_id` array.

Comment: perhaps you want to use `where()` instead of `find()`

Comment: To ping people you need to put an @ before their name. Like this: @har2vey.

Comment: @har2vey this is the entire show section of the controller, hope this sheds some light on the logic –

Comment: your controller still doesn't explain how the duplicated courses need to be displayed in the view, assuming that you want to display the multiple courses in customer order then your foreach loop should be using $orders->courses instead of $courses

Comment: @har2vey updated the question with view output.

Answer (score 2):

"Find" returns a single result based on primary key. Use that when you're looking for a single specific result.

"Where" returns all results matching your restriction. Use this when you want multiple results.

Comment: Where doesn't make a difference, no values are showing now using:   $courses = Course::with('orders')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->where($course_id);

Comment: Or would the restriction be: 
    $courses = Course::with('orders')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->where('id', 
    $course_id)->get();

Answer (score 1):

After reading your view, you should change your query in your controllers like this (assuming that you've created all the necessary relationship in your model)

```
$orders = Order::with(['courses','campuses','delivery_modes'])->orderBy('id', 'asc')->find($order_id);
```

what that'll do is pulling the orders of the particular customer along with the courses, location/campus, and delivery mode all in a single query so you don't need to query $courses $campuses $delivery_modes anymore, then in your view you just need to loop the **$orders->courses, $orders->campuses, $orders->delivery_modes** to list down all those information